# how to create an sql table without using create keyword?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

is there any options available to create a new sql table without using 'create' keyword

Comment: `select into` comes to mind. But why do you not want to use `create`?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: I asked only for earning extra knowledge.

Comment: how can we create a table with select into? can you give me some example?

Comment: also with select  into you need  the create table  statements  eg: create table my_table  select  * from other_table

Comment: The only thing I can think of (if it's about Oracle), is to create a materialized view, which implicitly creates a table ...

Comment: You can use select into command for that in mySql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example this is a table named as `Emp` and you create a table named as `Emp_Copy`

```
EmployeeID  EmployeeName  Age   Gender  
1001        Henry         54    Male    
1002        Tina          36    Female  
1003        John          24    Male
```

for selecting all columns

```
SELECT * INTO Emp_Copy FROM Emp;
```

for selecting some columns

```
SELECT EmployeeID,  EmployeeName ,Age INTO Emp_Copy FROM Emp;
```